# DocuSign Organizations management through API

Tags: docusignapi, identity-management

Me and my team are facing an identity and management project where `DocuSign` should be integrated with `IdentityIQ` to manager its user accounts and permissions.

As you all know, DocuSign works as follows:

1. An organization
2. One or more accounts that belong to the organization
3. Users that belongs to organization

Our client needs users being able to request account permissions, but also organization admin role.

We are using the `API` to integrate `DocuSign` with `IdentityIQ` and handle its requirements, but we do not know, because it is not in the documentation, how Organization permissions can be assigned to users through `API`. Do you have any experience on this?

Thank you in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

At this time, Organization Admin functionality is not exposed in the DocuSign API.